# How to clear all input fields after submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, post

I am using this function for posting my `form`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ".",
    data: {'postdata':allVals,
                   csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
    success: function(responseText) {
        console.log("Posted Data");
    }
});
```

This function is called on a button click event which then posts the data. Now please tell me how can I clear all the input fields as soon as the data is posted successfully.
Please help!

Comment: Try `$(':input').val('')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...call this in success

```
 success: function(responseText) {
            $('#form input').attr('value','');//        console.log("Posted Data");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try...

```
$('form')[0].reset();
```

...inside your success callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code into your success method.

```
success: function(responseText) {
    console.log("Posted Data");
    $('#yourform :input').val('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':input','#myform')
    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
    .val('')
    .removeAttr('checked')
    .removeAttr('selected');
```